# Allow IIS virtual directory to pass through to a separate http.sys binding

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, http.sys

**Bottom line: Is there a way to allow a subpath of a bound IIS site pass through to a non-IIS application bound directly in http.sys?**

I am using IIS 7.5 on Windows Server 2008. I have an existing IIS site bound to a specific root url, say `fooapps.bar.com`. This site has several applications and directories underneath it. All this works great. The problem is I now want to allow a subpath of `fooapps.bar.com` to passthrough to another service that registers itself directly with http.sys, NOT an IIS application.

So this service binds itself with http.sys at `fooapps.bar.com/Services`. If I stop the IIS site bound to `fooapps.bar.com`, then the requests to `fooapps.bar.com/Services` are successfully received and handled by the http.sys-bound service. However, if the IIS site is running then all requests to `fooapps.bar.com/Services/*` get intercepted by IIS and return errors because there is nothing actually at the corresponding physical path. How can I tell IIS to completely ignore `fooapps.bar.com/Services` and instead let requests to that path pass through to whatever else happens to be bound in http.sys?

```
fooapps.bar.com (site)
   + Files (normal directory with static .html files)
   + SomeApp1 (application)
   + SomeApp2 (application)
   + nuget
       + Feed1 (application)
       + Feed2 (application)
       + Feed3 (application)
   + Services (??? How to make this pass through to separate http.sys binding?)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create namespace reservation for required subtree.
In command line with administrative privileges execute:

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://fooapps.bar.com:80/Services/ user=<samUserName>
```

Use user name your non-IIS application is running under.